# JsTree dnd single items

Tags: javascript, jstree

I'm using JsTree 3.0.2 with dnd and checkbox plugins. This are my current settings

```
$('#dataTree').jstree({
            "core": {
                "themes": {
                    "responsive": false
                },
                "check_callback": true,
                'data': [...]
            },
            "checkbox": {
                "keep_selected_style": false
            },
            "types": {
                "default":{
                    "max_depth": 0,
                    "icon": "fa fa-list icon-state-success icon-lg"
                },

            },
            "plugins": ["contextmenu", "dnd", "types","checkbox"]
 });
```

The problem is when I drag an item all checked items are dragged. How can I prevent this? I want to maintain checked items but only drag hovered one.

Thanks